# How to import selected rows from one tab to another

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have Sheet 1 with categorized data. The 'Status' column is what I want to selectively use to pull rows from Sheet 1 -> Sheet 2. I'm trying to find the most straightforward way to pull over just Rows that have the status as 'Accept'. I was able to do this in a less concise, 2-step process of:

1. Column 1: Pull over *Just name column* of other sheet with criteria satisfied

   `=sort(filter('Data'!C2:C, {Status Cirteria}))`

*This was only needed once, and the rest of the column was populated automatically via =CONTINUE().

2. Column 2: pull over the remaining data (rest of row) corresponding to that name

   `=filter(Data!$A$3:T, {NameCell}=RawData!$F$3:F)`

*This was needed for every row.

I'd like to complete this process with just two functions that continue if possible, so I can eliminate user error associated with forcing the user to manually drag the second formula down for new entries.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using query instead of filter?

Assuming the status is at column F:

=query(Data!A3:T;"select * where F = 'Accept'";1)